# Kubuntu 15.04 : Brightness controls not working vs 2 graphic cards?

Tags: kubuntu, brightness, 15.04, i915

Just installed Kubuntu 15.04 on my ASUS X555LD (i3) to try out KDE 5.2, and I'm having a few issues.

1. Brightness controls are not working using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd>
2. I'm a bit confused. My laptop ships with an Nvidia graphics card. So
   why is the Intel module being loaded?

When I run `lspci -v` I get the following output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Wait just a sec.. Intel? But isn't my graphics card an NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 820M 2GB DDR3 com VRAM?

So why is it modprobing the i915 driver?
Shouldn't it be loading just the noveau driver, period?

As to the brightness controls, any thoughts?
`acpi_backlight=vendor` didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Brightness control buttons do not produce events due to an outdated kernel driver. It can be fixed by adding "acpi_osi=" boot parameter, just like you added "acpi_backlight=vendor".

So add "acpi_osi=" instead.